# PHP echo in rows of three?

Tags: php, logic, modulus

I am attempting to show data in rows of three like this (notice the number of items will not always be even):

> ```
> abcd defg hijk
> lmno pqrs tuvw
> xyz1 2345 6789 
> 1011 1213
> ```

I am struggling to get the logic right to do this (this is in a `foreach()` loop).

I know I have to have some `if($i %3 == 0)` logic in there.. But I'm a bit stuck.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = array('abcd','defg','hijk','lmno');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
  if ($i && $i % 3 == 0)
    echo '<br />';
  echo $a[$i].' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a `for` loop as:

```
// run $i for each index in the array.
for($i=0 ; $i<count($arr) ; $i++) {

        // if $i is non-zero and is divisible by 3 print a line break.
        if ($i && $i % 3 == 0) {
                echo "<br />";
        }

        // print the element at index $i.
        echo $arr[$i].'&nbsp;';
}
```

[**Code in action**](http://codepad.org/BUaJJSv9)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code since I don't know PHP (and you asked for the logic which tends to be the same across all procedural languages):

```
perline = 3
i = 0
foreach item in list:
    if i > 0 and (i % perline) == 0:
        print newline
    if (i % perline) != 0:
        print space
    print item
    i = i + 1
```

This will both output a line separator before elements 3, 6, 9 and so on (first element being 0) *and* place whatever desired spacing you want before the second and third elements on each line. You can just use a different value for `perline` to change the number output on each line.